# Django and Huey task issue, record in DB doesn't exist when the task is ran

Tags: python, django, redis, python-huey

I am testing Huey with Django and found one issue, tasks can't find the record in DB.

- Postgres 14
- Redis 7.0.5
- Django 4
- use with docker

Here is the code:

```
# settings.py
USE_HUEY = env.bool("USE_HUEY", False)
HUEY = {
    "huey_class": "huey.RedisHuey", 
    "name": "huey",
    "immediate": not USE_HUEY,
    "connection": {"url": REDIS_URL},
}


# app/signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def post_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    from app.tasks import create_or_update_related_objects
    create_or_update_related_objects(instance.pk)


# app/tasks.py
@db_task()
def create_or_update_related_objects(object_pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
    ...
```

This is running an async task but I am getting the error:

```
app.models.Post.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

This is not correct, there is a post, and this task is running on a `post_save` signal.

What is weird, is if I do something like this, it works fine:

```
@db_task()
def create_or_update_related_objects(object_pk):
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use `transaction.on_commit` on `signal.py`:

```
# app/signals.py
from django.db import transaction


@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def post_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    from app.tasks import create_or_update_related_objects
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: create_or_update_related_objects(instance.pk))
```

This way I am sure that `Post` object is saved to DB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but most likely your task will be completed before the database is committed. It seems that the `enqueue()` method can add your task to the queue so that the database has time to commit.